# Attempt to present <DeviceDetailViewController...while presentation is in progress. any ideas?

Tags: iphone, ios, output

I have this warning in the output however it is not coming up as an 'issue' (I have no issues at the moment). However in my output I get:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <DeviceDetailViewController: 0x84a7340> on   <UINavigationController: 0x74a14f0> while a presentation is in progress!
```

While its not affecting my code in terms of crashing or warnings/issues, its bugging me!

Thanks all!

I did a search on google and hear and could not find anything with this question - similar ones but no help.

Updated question:

I have this in my code:

```
#pragma mark - Segue

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"UpdateRecords"]) {
        NSManagedObject *selectedDevice = [self.devices objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView   indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
    DeviceDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.device = selectedDevice;
}
}

- (IBAction)addButtonPressed:(id)sender {

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"register" sender:self];
}
```

the addButton method "registers" (performs the register seque) the user if there are no users, and Update register seque goes to the same screen but allows you to update the details.

Hope Im clear.

Comment: You are attempting to present a view controller (probably by calling `presentViewController:animated:completion:`) while another view controller is still being animated on screen.  Don't do that.

Comment: @AaronBrager - Im calling    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];   which is similar to what youre telling me not to do yes? Do you have a solution?

Comment: What you're doing should be ok, if you're not also doing another transition at the same time. You should show the code (whole method) where you get this warning. Make sure that you're not firing a segue and calling a method that moves between view controller in code at the same time.

Comment: @gcorkc - It's fine to present a view controller of course - the issue is you're presenting two at the same time.

Comment: @rdelmar - I posted an update above, the problem is the firing of the segues

Comment: @AaronBrager -  unintentionally I am.

Comment: If you have a segue connected to your button in the storyboard, then you shouldn't be calling performSegueWithIdentifier in code. Is that what you're doing? If so, just delete the addButtonPressed method.

Comment: @rdelmar - what I have is two seperate buttons that go to the same view. Let me explain, if there is no one registered then there is an edit but that bring you to a form where you register. This is a register button, however if you are register, then this button is hidden, and an edit button appears. so yes i have two buttons linked to the same segue

Comment: The fact that you have two buttons is not relevant. Are these buttons connected directly to the segue in IB -- that is, did you drag from the button, not the controller? If so, that in itself triggers the segue, so you should eliminate the button's action method as I said above.

Comment: Thanks @rdelmar that did the trick! No more warning. Which is better practice, having segues connected to buttons or controllers? I was taught only the controller way and then to call an action...apologies for the confusion

Comment: Usually, you only connect to the controller if there's a need to do so. Like, if you have to decide which segue to perform when you click the button. If you only have one segue, then connecting directly from the button is preferred.

Comment: @rdelmar. Thank you. I gave you a vote-up.  Your suggestion works for my problem.  I had the same problem with buttons' event handler when calling "performSegueWithIdentifier" in event handler (button touch inside).  I do not know when I should use "performSegueWithIdentifier"?

Answer (score -1):

The *right* way to solve this is to not call storyboard segues or present view controllers from methods that could be called as a result of a view transition.  For example, don't present a view controller from `viewDidLoad`; present it from `viewDidAppear` instead.

An easy hack is to delay the presentation by 3/4 of a second, like so:

```
double delayInSeconds = 0.75;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [self presentViewController:myVC animated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

Depending on your view hierarchy, it's possible that this might have unintended side effects.

Comment: Thanks @AaronBrager it looks like a good solution however it cause my project to crash - must be my view hierarchy

Comment: Try increasing the `delayInSeconds` - it just needs to be a little higher than the amount of time your segue transition is.